# Matlab is not reading a .mat file

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm trying to read a .mat file and trying to plot the signal and its magnitude (half period). My code is

```
    %Read EEG (.mat)
    EEG_read = load('EEG.mat');
    f_EEG = 100; %frequency
    n3 = 0:1/100:pi;
    subplot(2, 1, 1)
    plot(EEG_read)
    xlabel('t(s)') %signal
    legend('EEG')
    subplot(2, 1, 2)
    plot(n3, abs(fft(EEG_ler))) %DFT
    xlabel('f(Hz)')
    legend('DFT EEG')
```

Thanks in advance.

Note: The .mat file is a part of a real EEG and it contains only one variabe 1x2000, struct type

Comment: Looks alright, which line is giving you an error?

Comment: @MichaelTr7 in plot(EEG_read)

Comment: Maybe you could post what is loaded from the `.mat` file that way we can see what variables you have loaded and how they are configured.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 just did it

Comment: Click on the `EEG_read ` structure and see the name of the matrices available. There's no need to do this assignment `EEG_read = load('EEG.mat');`. Simply using `load('EEG.mat');` will load and allow access to all the saved variables.

Comment: Or you can `.` dot index the variable you need from that structure. Using the workspace window on the right will help with viewing the types.

Comment: Wait, @MichaelTr7 variable is of struct type, I'm going to change

Comment: Just got it, @MichaelTr7 ! Thanks a lot for helping. The thing is that it worked plotting  EEG_read.data

Answer (score 1):

### Methods of Loading and Accessing `.mat` Data

If you have saved a variable named `EEG_read` in a MATLAB file there are two ways to access it. You have two ways of loading the `.mat`. Option 1 is to load all the data/variables into a structure. Option 2 is to load all the data/variables directly into the workspace.

---

### Accessing Variables From `.mat` Loaded Structure:

This method loads all the `.mat` data into a structure in this case I called the structure `Structure`. Within this structure, all the variables in the `.mat` file can be accessed by `.` indexing each member of this structure. Since there is only one variable in this structure called `EEG_read` we can access this variable by calling `Structure.EEG_read`.

[image: Accessing From Structure]

```
Structure = load('EEG.mat');
subplot(2, 1, 1); plot(Structure.EEG_read);
```

---

### Loading all Variables from `.mat` and Directly into the Workspace

This method will load all the workspace variables within the `.mat file` exactly as when they were saved. The variable names will remain the same as they were when saved.

[image: Loading all Workspace Variables]

```
load('EEG.mat');
subplot(2, 1, 1); plot(EEG_read);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Still not working @MichaelTr7, but I got it, thanks